# Using error codes instead of explicit checks in SQL?

Tags: sql, jdbc, primary-key, error-code

I have a query which attempts to insert a row into a table. It is possible that the query will fail due to a primary key contraint failing because there is already a row with that ID.

I could check for this before attempting the insert, but I can also detect this by checking the SQL state of an SQLException. Is this a valid way to do this type of thing? Or should I do the explicit check before hand?

The reason I ask is that if I do have to do the explicit check before I perform the insert, I will have to lock the table I am checking from in order to prevent inconsistency. Using the error code checking means I won't have to lock the table.

**Check beforehand**

```
try {
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = 123");
    if(rs.next()) {
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
        System.err.println("Entry with Id 123 already exists!");
        return;
    }
    statement = con.createStatement();
    statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO SomeTable(Id) VALUES(123)");
    con.commit();
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // These 2 lines actually need to be wrapped in a try/catch too.
    con.rollback();
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

**Error code checking**

```
try {
    Statement = con.createStatement();
    statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO SomeTable(Id) VALUES(123)");
} catch(SQLException e) {
    if(e.getSQLState().equals("23505"))
        System.err.println("Entry with Id 123 already exists!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "error code checking" approach is valid and indeed is the convention. Note you can also parse the exception Message property for the name of the SQL constraint that was violated, which is why it is a good idea to make constraints granular (i.e. err on the side of creating many simple constraints rather than a few complex ones) and to give each a meaningful name.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to code defensively around such things. I would write my query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(ID)
SELECT 123
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable WHERE id = 123)
```

Of course, you'll have to modify that query depending on your flavor of SQL. Perhaps:

```
SELECT 123
FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS...
```

After the insert you can test your affected rowcount and determine whether or not there was a PK violation.

Comment: I don't understand how this significantly different from the OP's `Error code checking` approach, other than making the insert failure more opaque to the end user.

Comment: It's actually closer to the `check beforehand` approach but atomic (depending on the rdbms, which is not specified.) and doesn't require a serializable isolation level. Exception objects are generally costly to create and, from the OP's question, this exception is not particularly exceptional. It also requires less code and it's less work to parse out a true exception and decide whether or not to retry. Again, it's a personal preference; TMTOWTDI.

Comment: I agree, it's a valid approach. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid errors like this in the first place by using sequences or autoincrement columns for PKs.

However, proper handling of SQLExceptions is still necessary, as all kinds of other errors might occur.

Comment: I don't need a sequence or autoincrement column, I just don't want someone to be able to insert a row if a row with that ID already exists.